# let X be a random variable such that $E[X^4]=1$ then $P(|X|\geq 2) \leq \frac{1}{16}$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am trying to prove or disprove the following:

> let X be a random variable such that $E[X^4]=1$ then $P(|X|\geq 2)
>  \le \frac{1}{16}$?

It's obviously related to **Markov's inequality**.
Well, my attempt was to alter the original proof:

$$
E[X^n]=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n*f(x)dx \geq \int_{c}^{\infty}x^nf(x)dx\geq\int_{c}^{\infty}c^nf(x)dx=c^nP(X\geq c)
$$

then

$$ P(X\geq c) \leq \frac{E[X^n]}{c^n}$$

Given the following "proof" (I'm just not sure about it's validity), it's easy to see that, given that $ E[X^4] = 1$:

$$ P(X\geq 2) \leq \frac{1}{2^4}=\frac{1}{16}$$

Is that a valid proof?

Comment: Your integral starts at 0 which seems to assume X is non-negative, which is not given in the problem. If it were, this looks ok. Maybe you can show that if it holds for non-negative X it holds in general?

Comment: Doesn't this follow simply from $P(|X|\ge 2)=P(X^4\ge 2^4)\le \frac{1}{2^4}E(X^4)$ ?

Comment: The other 'complaint' would be that the random variable might not be continuous, so a  density function might not (classically) exist.  The (IMO easier, and general) argument would be that $P(|X|\ge 2)>\frac1{16}$ would imply $P(X^4\ge 16)>\frac1{16}$, hence you already have  a  measure bigger than one for $E(X^4)$, and that cannot decrease because $X^4\ge 0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom well I don't know haha. It does make sense, but I'm not in the position to say that with confident. If it does though, this problem is obviously much  simpler than what I though, as usual...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using the [Markov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) (or actually proving it in the process), using the expectation of indicator function on an event to denote the probability of the event, we get:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[|X|\geq 2]&=\mathbb E[\mathbf 1(|X|\geq 2)]\\
&=\mathbb E[\mathbf 1(|X|^4\geq 16)]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1\left(\frac{|X|^4}{16}\geq 1\right)\right]\\
&\leq \mathbb E\left[ \frac{|X|^4}{16}\right]\\
&=\frac{\mathbb E[X^4]}{16}\\
&=\frac{1}{16}
\end{align*}

Since $\frac{|X|^4}{16}$ is a positive random variable.

---

To see why $\mathbf 1(a\geq 1)\leq a$ for $a\geq 0$, it is sufficient to observe that if $a<1$, then $\mathbf 1(a\geq 1)=0\leq a$ and for $a\geq 1$, $\mathbf 1(a\geq 1)=1\leq a$